# Angular 2: Materialize Labels overlapping prefilled content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I'm having problem with dynamic data and input field

[image]

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" value="{{ candidates.name }}">
  <label id="newName" for="name" class="active">Name</label>
</div>
```

I looked at Google and GitHub how to fix it, and don't found any solution.
I tried to add `active` class, but it don't work.
I tried use jQuery too `$('#newName').addClass('active');` and it not work too

in console I have this:

[image]

How can I fix it? Anyone could help me?

Comment: Could you prepare a Plunker sample to illustrate the issue in action?

Comment: Thanks, but I got to fix the problem. It was because I'm using `jQuery` with `materialize`, when I remove this import the input field was fixed

Comment: Great to hear that the issue was resolved! I believe it makes sense to post your solution as an answer to this thread.